# Rings in SOME of my canon 5D mIV shots

Tags: canon, sigma, canon-5d-mark-iv

[image]New camera - old lens.  I shot these with the Sigma Art 35mm on my new Canon.  It's not on every shot.  has anyone see these before?  Looks like it MIGHT be happening with shallow depth of field.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 15):

It is a common problem when using some 3rd party lenses. Just turn off the in-camera lens corrections.

[image]

Comment: Do both need to be disabled, or just the `Peripheral illumination correction`?

Comment: Yes, Disable both.

Comment: This is fascinating, I would love to know how exactly this happens. Judging by the sharpness of the rings, it looks like a software bug.

Comment: @JohnEye if I had to make a wild guess, the third party lens is returning an invalid/maximum/out-of-range value for something the camera is trying to read from it, making the camera apply a totally maxed out and incorrect "correction" to the image.